# Tracking mouse movements

Tags: javascript, jquery

This should be typically easy, I want to perform tracking of mouse movements. I'm capable of capturing the XY co-ords.

However, as far as I'm aware, this will vary according to the browser size, right ?

If so, can anyone recommend other things to track to ensure my results are accurate?

P.s I'm using the following Jquery example

```
$("html").mousemove(function(e){
var pageCoords = "( " + e.pageX + ", " + e.pageY + " )";
var clientCoords = "( " + e.clientX + ", " + e.clientY + " )";
$("span:first").text("( e.pageX, e.pageY ) - " + pageCoords);
$("span:last").text("( e.clientX, e.clientY ) - " + clientCoords);
});
```

Comment: What problem are you facing that would be affected by different page sizes?

Comment: If OP Wants to track mouse movements, a large browser window will cause larger x values if the page content is centered..

Comment: PS: made a fiddle: http://fiddle.jshell.net/t2AG2/6/show/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Coordinates are independent of the browser size.

Hope this helps. Cheers

PS: Use `$(window).mousemove` or `$(document).mousemove` instead of `$("html").mousemove`, it's a better practice.

Comment: But for instance what will happen if someone is on a 800x600 browser screen and scrolls down the page, will the dimensions not represent the browsers current view of the page after the scroll?

Comment: `pageY` gives you the mouse location relative to the document origin, so if mouse is at 200 pixels below the top of the document and the user scrolls down 100, then the mouse will now be at 300.

Comment: `clientY` gives you the mouse location relative to the browser viewport, so it doesn't change when the page scrolls. Usually `pageY` is what you want because it reports the mouse position relative to your content. For more see https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/event.pageY and https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/event.clientY.